# c# Yield WaitForSeconds or Time.Deltatime

Tags: c#

I am making a game in Unity 5 with c# and I was wondering about Yield vs Time.Deltatime. Let's say that the "Money" should go up by "x" every second, should I use

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
```

or just use

```
Money += moneyModifier * Time.Deltatime;
```

Comment: Time.DeltaTime gives the ellapsed time between frames, you should probably use 'yield return new WaitForSeconds(1)';

Comment: First one, `WaitForSeconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Money += moneyModifier * Time.Deltatime;` would have to be called every frame to work the way you want, as `Time.Deltatime` only gives you the time which has passed since the last frame has been drawn. (I.e. it must be placed in `Update()` and must be called every frame. Not very resource-friendly).

This method is more appriopate to be implemented as a coroutine.

```
public int Money;

public IEnumerator IncreaseMoney(int amount, float interval) 
{
     while(true)
     {
          Money += amount;
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);   
     }
}

//somewhere within this class
void Start() 
{
   //Start increasing the money by 50 every 2 seconds
   StartCoroutine(IncreaseMoney(50, 2.0)); 
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the answers :) Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution will increase the character's money once every second, like the seconds hand of a clock.

Assuming you run it in the `update` logic of your game loop, your solution with `Time.Deltatime` will constantly increase the player's money, by the same<sup>1</sup> amount *per second*
(think Money in *Sim City* / *Cities:Skylines* or Gold in *League of Legends*)

If you want the money of the player to constantly increase (like for a economy-strategy-game) go for the second solution, if you want it to stay constant for every second and rise by a fixed amount between, go for the first solution.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> not by exactly the same amount, since `WaitForSeconds(1)` will most likely wait *at least* 1 second, sometimes a few milliseconds more.

Comment: Thank you! :) Very helpful Indeed! Thank you for answer as well!